# Doctrine php DBAL not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

New to [doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) php and I followed each instruction to the point. Downloaded doctrine using composer as instructed on http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html and then on my index.php I added this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#getting-a-connection only changing the test database credentials.

```
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();

$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'teastdb',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);


$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
```

and this does not work (shows blank page, I even inserted both right and wrong credential for testing purpose). What is wrong?

Here is a screenshot as well

[image]

Comment: Is there more code after the $conn = statement?  What did you expect to show?  In any event, add "error_reporting(E_ALL);" to the top of the file and see if that generates an error message.

Comment: @Cerad, no there are no more codes after $conn, I did add error_reporting earlier to see what errors I have but it showed nothing. I have a database named 'testdb' and entered the wrong database name 'teastdb', yet it shows no error. It's a dead white screen on load.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried your file and got no errors as well.  Merely creating a connection object does not access the database.  Add: $schema = $conn->getSchemaManager(); and you will get an error.  Just means that creating a connection has little overhead.  It's only when you use it that the database stuff happens.